# Problems with 20.04 desktop

Tags: 20.04

I've been a Linux user for almost two decades and for almost all of that time a Ubuntu user. (I did use Fedora for a bit at the start.)
I'm an ordinary user, the kind that developers delight in, because it gives them someone to whom to demonstrate their obvious superiority.
For the past five years, I've been using version 16.04. Because support for it was about to end, I knew I had to upgrade, so yesterday I did. I upgraded to version 18.04. Since that worked, I thought I might as well go all the way to version 20.04, so that I won't have to worry about losing support again unless I live for four more years (not a highly probable outcome, given my current age and the state of the world).
Now I have a desktop that's practically useless: can't arrange the icons on it; can't cut or copy items from or paste items to the desktop; can't choose the application to open a file with.
The simple answer: just buy a Mac. I don't want to give in like that after all these years.
I've seen suggestions as to how to get a usable desktop back, but I don't understand enough to know how to implement them or whether they really work.
One suggestion I saw was to install nemo; another was to install a particular desktop extension, but I don't know what either would do to mess up all the application icons I have in my top and bottom panels.
I'd love to hear from anyone who actually has their desktop working like it used to for the last twenty years in all operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor, and do a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04. Upgrades are not always seamless. Installing a fresh system ensures that the whole system can be setup as the developers intended and tested. At the same time, your system for once is thoroughly cleaned up. You will end up with a solid new system that will serve you reliably for many years to come.

A fresh install removes all files on the system. Obviously, but also before doing any other system intervention, you need to make sure your backup of your personal files is up to date, because you will need to place the data back. Your personal data, once lost, are lost forever. An operating system, on the other hand, is downloaded anytime and installed in under one hour.

Comment: and use clonezilla to do a full backup.

Comment: Just rsync to safeguard your data will do and will be much quicker.

Comment: and if you cannot boot to ubuntu  if it all goes pear shaped please put your instructions here on how easy it is using rsync.... (by the way I have given up on desktop usage as I had to uninstall nautilus to get rid of tracker. I just use the Desktop folder in Krusader). note I am suggesting CZ for system backup, for individual files to restore once booted into Ubuntu, sure use rsync.

Comment: Fresh install is allright, but then still you don´t have the Desktop properties like they used to be under 16.04. I did not notice before, because I am using Nautilus to arrange my files, but my girlfriend does not and is unhappy with the new Desktop on 20.04. She wants the posibilty to drag and drop files.